# Get the previous element of a double linked List

Tags: java, list, sorting

Here's the class declaring my variables:

```
private class MyListElement {

    private final Integer value;
    private MyListElement nextElement;

    private MyListElement(final Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Here's how I add an element to my list:

```
private void addNewElement() {
    System.out.print("Please type the number to be added to the list: ");

    Integer newValue = null;
    while (newValue == null) {
        try {
            newValue = Integer.parseInt(userInput.nextLine());
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Wrong value. Please insert new value.");
        }
    }

    MyListElement newElement = new MyListElement(newValue);

    if (firstElement != null) {
        placeElementInList(newElement);
    } else {
        firstElement = newElement;
    }
}
```

And finally, the problem: First, I declare a variable to contain the last element on the list; that's okay. But how could I get its previous element to loop through the list and print it in reverse?

```
private void printInReverse() {
    MyListElement tmpElement = firstElement;
    while (tmpElement.nextElement != null) {
        tmpElement = tmpElement.nextElement;
    }

    MyListElement firstReverseElement = tmpElement;

    MyListElement elementInList = firstReverseElement;
    while (elementInList != null) {
        System.out.print(elementInList.value + ", ");
        elementInList = elementInList.nextElement;
    }
    System.out.println("");

}
```

The "elements" are hypothetical pointers to the values on list.

EDIT:
This is how I sort the list (ascending order).

```
private void placeElementInList(final MyListElement newElement) {
    if (newElement.value < firstElement.value) {
        newElement.nextElement = firstElement;
        firstElement = newElement;
    } else {
        MyListElement previousElement = firstElement;
        MyListElement elementInList = firstElement.nextElement;
        while (elementInList != null) {
            if (newElement.value < elementInList.value) {
                break;
            }
            previousElement = elementInList;
            elementInList = elementInList.nextElement;
        }
        previousElement.nextElement = newElement;
        newElement.nextElement = elementInList;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need another param  private MyListElement prevElement; in MyListElement class.

Comment: @Aeshang Okay, but it points to what? That's where I'm stuck at.

Comment: In a double linked list: first->prev is null, last->next is null. Lets say you have 2 consecutive elements p and q, then p->next is q, q->prev is p . .

Comment: Your previous element of course and how you loop through the nextElements you should be able to loop through the previous elements...
@DeiAndrei also it should have an head and a tail pointer ... That is the start and the end element pointers.

Answer (score 1):

That's why it's double linked: you need a link to the next as well as the previous element. No other ways, if I managed to understand your problem exactly.

Comment: Can you post your placeElementInList method?

Comment: well, the previous element is you list's currently last element. You need to be able to refer to that when you insert a new element. That should be possible with application of basic OO paradigms :D

Comment: @DeiAndrei Yes, just posted in the question.

Answer (score 0):

To have a previous element, just add a new instance variable to the element clasS:

private class MyListElement {

```
private final Integer value;
private MyListElement nextElement;
private MyListElement prevElement;

private MyListElement(final Integer value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

When you are adding the first element, which is here:

```
else {
    firstElement = newElement;
}
```

your first element is also the last element (A linked list is defined by its first AND last element). Therefore, it should be like:

```
firstElement = newElement;
lastElement = firstElement;
```

And finally, in your placeElementInList(newElement); method, once you have found the place of the newElement, just make a connection to the previous one.

Comment: How could I make this connection?